# Python: Programatically create an xml file which lists all the contents of a directory Recursively

Tags: xml, python-3.x

My directory structure looks like this. Here `test` is root directory, which contains directories `a` and `b`. `a` and `b` further contains subdirectories `a1` ,`a2` and `b1` ,`b2` respectively. Also `a1` contains file named `text`.

[image]

I have created xml file for this structure using [The ElementTree XML API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) as follows.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

test =  ET.Element('test')
a = ET.SubElement(test,'a')
a1 = ET.SubElement(a,'a1')
text = ET.SubElement(a1,'text')
a2 = ET.SubElement(a,'a2')
b = ET.SubElement(test,'b')
b1 = ET.SubElement(b,'b1')
b2 = ET.SubElement(b,'b2')
ET.dump(test)
```

The output of above program is

```
<test>
    <a>
        <a1>
            <text />
        </a1>
        <a2 />
    </a>
    <b>
        <b1 />
        <b2 />
    </b>
</test>
```

But, I need to generate the xml  Programatically for any given directory.
Is this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a recursive attempt using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import Path
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def xml_dir(pth, et_element=None):

    if et_element is None:
        et_element = ET.Element(pth.name)
    else:
        et_element = ET.SubElement(et_element, pth.name)

    for file in (fle for fle in pth.iterdir() if fle.is_file()):
        ET.SubElement(et_element, file.name)

    for directory in (fle for fle in pth.iterdir() if fle.is_dir()):
        xml_dir(directory, et_element)

    return et_element

ret = xml_dir(Path('/home/user/startdir/'))
```

this creates a fresh `ET.Element` at the beginning and then attaches `ET.SubElement`s for every sub-directory.

you may want to additionally sort the files and directories...

---

if you need a pretty-printed xml output you need this indent function (from http://effbot.org/zone/element-lib.htm#prettyprint)

```
def indent(elem, level=0):
    i = "\n" + level*"  "
    if len(elem):
        if not elem.text or not elem.text.strip():
            elem.text = i + "  "
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
            elem.tail = i
        for elem in elem:
            indent(elem, level+1)
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
            elem.tail = i
    else:
        if level and (not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip()):
            elem.tail = i
```

and using that you get a nice string representation of the element tree:

```
ret = xml_dir(Path('/home/user/startdir/'))
indent(ret)
ET.dump(ret)
```

or, if you want to save the string in a variable:

```
strg = ET.tostring(ret, method='xml').decode()
```

Comment: sorry. assumed you were familiar with `ElementTree`; added pretty-print function.

Comment: When I try to return ET.dump(ret) from a function, it raises `AttributeError- 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'iter'`. pls help

Comment: yes, its none. but how do i correct that? I'm using the above function `xml_dir`. That way, ret is already an instance of ET.Element. Is'nt it?

Comment: I've `xml_dir` and `indent` functions same as above. below that I've `def xml_output(path_of_dir):
    ret = indent(xml_dir(Path(path_of_dir)))
    return(ret)`

Comment: oh, right. `indent` does not return anything (see code in my answer; it's just `indent(ret)` and not `ret = indent(ret)`); you should not assign `ret` to it... if you prefer you can add `return elem` at the very end of the indent function; then your line will work.

Comment: It works without using indent. But if I use `ret=indent(ret)`, then it returns `None`.

Comment: @kashish: yes, as i said: `indent` returns `None`. i suggested 2 ways to fix that in my last comment...